# How to fill NaN value of date time based on another coloumn +1?

Tags: python

I have a dataset like this:

| Join date | Pay date 1 | Pay date 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 Nov 2011 | NaN | NaN |

How is the code if I wanna fill the NaN with a date one month after the join date?
Expected result:

| join date | Pay date 1 | Pay date 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 Nov 2011 | 11 Dec 2011 | 11 Jan 2012 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you set up a list of months eg. `months='Jan', 'Feb, 'Mar'` etc., and then use a simple algorithm to change month (and possibly year) eg.

```py
dateIn="11 Mar 2011"   #the data comes into this variable
dateIn=dateIn.split(" ")#changes to ["11","Mar","2011"] which is easier to work with
day, month, year= dateIn[0], dateIn[1], int(dateIn[2])#gets the parts of the date seperated

if month == months[len(months)-1]: #last month so we change the year
    year+=1 #add to year
    month=months[0] #reset month
else:
    #is not the last month
    for m in months:
        if m == month:
            month=months[months.index(month)-1] #finds the next month and updates the month
dateOut=f"{day} {month} {year}" #reformats to an output (in this case "11 Apr 2011")
```

The input and output would need to be delt with (I don't know how your dataset works) and you would probably want to change this to a function but it would work for you.

Comment: what is date1 in line 2 refer to? dataframe's name?

Comment: btw its error on this code month=months[months.index(month)+1], it said list index out of range

Comment: I fixed the code to work now

Comment: Btw i already fixed too by add break before DateOut code.  Anyway thankss